# распарсить текстовый файл и получить массив вида array( "(0:00)"=>"text1","(0:30)"=>"text2")

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть тестовый файл вида

```
(0:00)

text1

text2

(0:30)

text text text text text

..................
```

нужно получить массив вида ключ - это значение в скобках, а значение - это тест.

```
array("(0:00)"=>"text1 text2","(0:30)"=>"text text text text text")
```

пишу следующее:

```
    $key = array();
    $val = array();
    $out = array();
    $file = file('1.txt');
    foreach($file as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (preg_match("/(\d{0,2}:\d\d)/",$line,$match)){
            $key[]=$match;
        }else{
            $val[]=$match;
        }
        $out=array_merge($key,$val);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($out);
```

подскажите как исправить?

Comment: `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = file_get_contents('1.txt');
preg_match_all("~\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)~", $text, $keys);
$values = array_values(preg_grep("~.+~", preg_split("~\(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\)~", $text)));
$final = [];
for ($n = 0; $n < count($keys[0]); $n++) {
    $final[$keys[0][$n]] = $values[$n];
}
print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 5):

Если вы все-равно извлекаете все содержимое файла при помощи функции `file()` в оперативную память, может тогда обойтись без массива? Извлеките содержимое файла в одну строку при помощи функции `file_get_contents()`. Будет гораздо удобнее получить все вхождения, например при помощи `preg_match_all()`, а потом на основании полученного ответа (ниже это `$results`), сформировать нужный вам массив `$out`

```
<?php
$out = array();
$file = file_get_contents('1.txt');
preg_match_all("/(\(\d{0,2}:\d{2}\))([^\(]+)/", $file, $results);
foreach($results[1] as $key => $value) {
  $out[$results[1][$key]] = $results[2][$key];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$key = '';
$val = array();
$out = array();
$file = file('1.txt');
foreach($file as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if (preg_match("/(\d{0,2}:\d\d)/",$line,$match)){
        $key = $match;
    }else{
        $val[$key][] = $match;
    }

}
foreach($val as $k=>$v) $val[$k] = implode(' ',$v);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($val);
```

Comment: Warning: Illegal offset type on line 11